# React router not showing a page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hello I'm using react router dom for routing but I have a problem right now because it doesn't load only one of my pages. Other pages works correctly but my about page is showing a blank page. In my localhost works fine in every page but when I deploy it to my host, only my about page shows a blank page. any reason?

MainRouter:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Loading from './components/Loading';

const Header = lazy(() => import('./components/Header'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/Home'));
const ResearchPrograms = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/ResearchPrograms'));
const ContactUs = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/ContactUs'));
const GICR = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/GICR'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/About'));
const Investors = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/Investors'));
const Team = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/Team'));
const Footer = lazy(() => import('./components/Footer'));
const NotFound = lazy(() => import('./components/Pages/Page404'));

const MainRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/researchPrograms" component={ResearchPrograms} />
          <Route path="/contactUs" component={ContactUs} />
          <Route path="/gicr" component={GICR} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/investors" component={Investors} />
          <Route path="/team" component={Team} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default MainRouter;
```

About:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, } from 'react';
import { Link, } from 'react-router-dom';
import DropdownMenu from '../DropdownMenu';
import HandleStyle from '../HandleJumpStyleAbout';

const About = () => {
  const firstParag = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const secondParag = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      HandleStyle(firstParag, secondParag);
    }, true);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', () => {
      HandleStyle(firstParag, secondParag);
    }, true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>
      <img className="about-image"
        src={require('../../AboutUs.jpg')}
        alt="main-wallpaper"
      />
      <div className="dropdownMenu-about">
        <DropdownMenu
          items={secondHeader}
          onPress={(index) => {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                handleJumpTo(firstParag, true);
                break;
              default:
                handleJumpTo(secondParag, true);
                break;
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Comment: try add `<Route exact path="/about" component={About} />` and I think `<Router>` is not necessary! remove it and test.

Comment: check if your about page is exported properly or not, the paths and the File name in coreect folder, this seems fine might be you have issue somewhere else

Comment: @b3hr4d it didn't work

Comment: @Ayushi Keshri yeah its correct. i dont know because it works well in my localhost

Comment: Have u deployed the bundle.js or the whole react , if whole try to put console and check the network tab aswell and debug it

Comment: I have deploted the whole react.

Comment: I think it should be from your path inside the host, check if there is `/about` directory inside your `public_html` exist. remove it and this should work. (if didn't work make a chat with me ill help you with that)

Comment: Error: Minified React error #152; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args[]=c for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. this the error in console

Comment: This error happens when you are passing an object as children in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Route inside the Switch HOC witch `exact` prop

```
   <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/researchPrograms" component={ResearchPrograms} />
          <Route exact path="/contactUs" component={ContactUs} />
          <Route exact path="/gicr" component={GICR} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/investors" component={Investors} />
          <Route exact path="/team" component={Team} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
```

Comment: it is inside the switch HOC and why did you use about 2 times?

Comment: my bad i didnt notice the /about route inside the switch HOC. can you post the About page code?